# Recursive tail function in GnuCOBOL 2.0 (with OpenCobolIDE 4.7.6)

Tags: function, recursion, cobol, tail, gnucobol

I’m new to COBOL and GnuCOBOL (in Windows).

I'm trying to write a recursive function with a tail, but the program does not return values it would be possible to help me. I wonder if what I want is possible in language?

Follows function code

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   FUNCTION-ID. FATBASE.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.

   DATA DIVISION.
   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  LS-NUM PIC 99.
   77  LS-PAR PIC 99.

   LINKAGE SECTION.
   77  LK-NUM PIC 99.
   77  LK-PAR PIC 99.
   77  LK-FAT PIC 9(33).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING BY VALUE LK-NUM, LK-PAR
   RETURNING LK-FAT.
       IF NUMVAL(LK-NUM) = 0
          COMPUTE LK-FAT = NUMVAL(LK-PAR)
       ELSE
          COMPUTE LS-NUM = LK-NUM - 1
          COMPUTE LS-PAR = LK-NUM * NUMVAL(LK-PAR)
          COMPUTE LK-FAT = NUMVAL(FATBASE(LS-NUM, LS-PAR))
       END-IF
       GOBACK.
   END FUNCTION FATBASE.
```

Follows code of the program that calls the function

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. TESTEFAT.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION FATBASE
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.

   DATA DIVISION.
   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  LS-NUM PIC 99.
   77  LS-FAT PIC Z(33).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       ACCEPT LS-NUM.
       MOVE FATBASE(LS-NUM, 1) TO LS-FAT
       DISPLAY FATBASE(LS-NUM, 1)
       STOP RUN.
```

As for the **IF/THEN** command, these are working properly. The problem is occurring with the COMPUTE commands. The lines with **COMPUTE** do not seem to be having the expected calculation effect. It seems that only the LS-NUM and LK-NUM variable have any value. The other variables are zeroed during processing.

```
       IF NUMVAL(LK-NUM) = 0
          COMPUTE LK-FAT = NUMVAL(LK-PAR)
       ELSE
          COMPUTE LS-NUM = LK-NUM - 1
          COMPUTE LS-PAR = LK-NUM * NUMVAL(LK-PAR)
          COMPUTE LK-FAT = NUMVAL(FATBASE(LS-NUM, LS-PAR))
       END-IF
```

In advance thanks for any help.

The programs are attached.

Best regards.

===========================================================================

At the end of the day after this post I got external help - available at: https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/cobol/thread/54637a961a/?limit=250#313c/7037/dbaf/3684

Comment: DISPLAY FATBASE(LS-NUM, 1)  <-  You're passing a 1 byte numeric constant in a position you defined with a length of 2.  Either pass the correct size, 01,  or better yet pass it in a field defined with PIC 99.

Answer (score 0):

Follows the base code of the factorial operation by tail

> ```
>    IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
>    FUNCTION-ID. FATBASE.
> ```

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.

   DATA DIVISION.
   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  LS-NUM PIC 99.
   77  LS-PAR PIC 9(33).

   LINKAGE SECTION.
   77  LK-NUM PIC 99.
   77  LK-PAR PIC 9(33).
   77  LK-FAT PIC 9(33).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING BY VALUE LK-NUM, LK-PAR
   RETURNING LK-FAT.
       IF LK-NUM = 0
          COMPUTE LK-FAT = LK-PAR
       ELSE
          COMPUTE LS-NUM = LK-NUM - 1
          COMPUTE LS-PAR = LK-NUM * NUMVAL(LK-PAR)
          COMPUTE LK-FAT = NUMVAL(FATBASE(LS-NUM, LS-PAR))
       END-IF
       GOBACK.
   END FUNCTION FATBASE.
```

Follows the code of the intermediate sub-routine of the factorial execution

> ```
>    IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
>    FUNCTION-ID. FATOR2.
> ```

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION FATBASE
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.

   DATA DIVISION.
   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  LS-NUM PIC 9(2).
   77  LS-PAR PIC 9(33).
```

|     LINKAGE SECTION.
       77  LK-NUM PIC 99.
       77  LK-FAT PIC 9(33).

```
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING LK-NUM RETURNING LK-FAT.
       MOVE NUMVAL(LK-NUM) TO LS-NUM
       MOVE 1 TO LS-PAR
       COMPUTE LK-FAT = NUMVAL(FATBASE(LS-NUM, LS-PAR))
       GOBACK.
   END FUNCTION FATOR2.
```

Follows the code of the program that uses the tail recursive factorial function.

> ```
>    IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
>    PROGRAM-ID. TESTEFAT.
> ```

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   REPOSITORY.
       FUNCTION FATOR2
       FUNCTION ALL INTRINSIC.

   DATA DIVISION.
   LOCAL-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  LS-NUM PIC 99.
   77  LS-FAT PIC Z(33).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       ACCEPT LS-NUM.
       MOVE FATOR2(LS-NUM) TO LS-FAT
       DISPLAY TRIM(LS-FAT).
       STOP RUN.
```